# XSLT select unknown nodes

Tags: xslt

I have some trouble with a special XML-document.

The XML has only 3 nodes like the below the example:

```
<solidName>

     <unknownNodeName>
          <everytimeTheSame>blablabla</everytimeTheSame>
          <everytimeTheSame2>blablabla</everytimeTheSame2>
          <unknownChildNodeName>
               <everytimeTheSame>blablabla</everytimeTheSame>
               <everytimeTheSame2>blablabla</everytimeTheSame2>
          </unknownChildNodeName>
       </unknownNodeName>
</solidName>
```

I need to select the unknownNodeName and the unknownChildNodeName to use the function 
`<xsl:value-of select="everytimeTheSame"/>` and so on. I tried to use a for-each select function, but I found no way to get the unknow Name of the node.

Are there any possibilities for my problem? Is it possible to say `<xsl:for-each select ="NodeNumberX">` or things like that `<xsl:for-each select ="/*/*">`

Comment: The syntax for the end tags in your XML is wrong: It should be `</endtag>` not `<\endtag>`.

Comment: Show what you've tried so that we can better understand your difficulty.

Comment: "*The XML has only 3 nodes like the below*" Actually the document has 6 nodes, 3 levels deep.

Comment: Oh I thought it is called nodes. So ok then I have a 3 level deep XML-File with 6 nodes an the depth is everytime the same. The U-nodes should be in the top of a table and then the F-nodes should follow and then the next U-node and its F-node childs and so on and so on. I tried to upload an image to display ist better, but I'm new here so I can't upload any graphic. The below example with the list ist perfect but it shlould be in a tabele. Maybe the list help to understand:

Comment: @th227 I have rolled back your question to its original form. If you have another, fundamentally different question, please post it as a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to use the function and so on

is not a good description of what you want to do.

Selecting "unknown nodes" (i.e. nodes whose name you do not know, but you do know their position in the document's tree) is trivial by using the `*` symbol in an XPath expression, possibly combined with a positional predicate.

For example:

```
/*/*/*[2]
```

will select the `<everytimeTheSame2>` element in your example.

Comment: That's it!!! Thank you very much! I looked for such an solution one complete day and haven't found anything.